# How to recieve/get data from card I click on using JS

Tags: javascript, html

At the moment I'm trying to solve the problem I'm having on getting information from each card I click on.

Here's my code...

**My HTML**

```html
<div class="card cards">
  <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/185266/isolated/lists/815ded7afc1c54dfb5a60f81f68f928b-pizza-slice-icon.png" class="card-img-top p-3" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title" id="${id}-product-name">Pizza</h5>
    <h5 class="text-muted fw-bold card-price" id="${id}-product-price">$12,50 PEN</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

**My JavaScript**

```js
const cards = document.getElementsByClassName("cards");

getCardInfo = (id) => {
    const cardName = document.getElementById(id + "-product-name").innerHTML;
    const cardPrice = document.getElementById(id + "-product-price").innerHTML;
    console.log({ cardName, cardPrice });
}

// get card clicked and send info to checkout basket
for (let i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
        cards[i].addEventListener("click", orderBasket = (itemName, itemPrice) =>{
        const orderList = document.getElementById('orderList');
        const orderItem = document.createElement('li');

        const orderItemName = document.createTextNode(itemName + ' $');
        const orderItemPrice = document.createTextNode(itemPrice + ' PEN');

        orderItem.appendChild(orderItemName);
        orderItem.appendChild(orderItemPrice);

        orderList.appendChild(orderItem);
        console.log(orderItem);
        getCardInfo();
    });
};
```

And after this I get back in the console...

```js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHTML')
```

**UPDATE**

```js
getCardInfo = (id) => {
    const cardName = document.getElementById(id + "-product-name");
    const cardPrice = document.getElementById(id + "-product-price");
    console.log({ cardName, cardPrice });
 }
```

I'm having trouble getting info from my id. Help?

Comment: You are not passing `id` to `getCardInfo()`

Comment: @ArleighHix That was a mistake, but now I'm getting `id is not defined`

Comment: I'm having trouble getting this info. `cardPrice, cardName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of selecting by ID, select the clicked card and look for the elements you need inside of the card with [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector).

```js
const getCardInfo = card => {
  const title = card.querySelector('.card-title');
  const price = card.querySelector('.card-price');
  
  return {
    title: title.textContent,
    price: price.textContent
  }
}

const onCardClick = card => {
  const { title, price } = getCardInfo(card);
  
  console.log(title, price);
};

document.addEventListener('click', event => {
  const target = event.target.closest('.card');
  
  if (target !== null) {
    onCardClick(target);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="card cards">
  <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/185266/isolated/lists/815ded7afc1c54dfb5a60f81f68f928b-pizza-slice-icon.png" class="card-img-top p-3" alt="...">
  
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title" id="54-product-name">Pizza</h5>
    <h5 class="text-muted fw-bold card-price" id="54-product-price">$12,50 PEN</h5>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very well done, not only did it work, but I understand it all and its so more readable. Plus, I learned about `.closest` and how it works. Will never forget that one. Thanks!